# Regex: match from this until that unless this other character is in the middle

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some text kinda like this:

`This is my text. I [##something#] have so much text [## it's really crazy. And it's not even [##something#] lorem ipsum [##.`

I'm using the `[##` and `#]` to be able to easy pick out the contents in between them with regex. But I need to match all the single `[##` in the text that doesn't have their couterpart `#]`.

I managed to match the last `[##` with no counterpart `#]`, but I haven't been able to match the single `[##` in the middle yet, because there is a `#]` coming up later in the text. I've been mixing negative and positive lookaheads, but haven't quite figured it out.

I've been trying variants of this: `/\[##(?!.+#])/g` with positive lookaheads to try to limit it only to check until the next `[##`.

Any help?

Comment: But what exactly do you need to do with this anchor (that doesn't have a counterpart)?

Comment: I have a textarea with a limit of 350 characters. The users can type in links with the link, followed by a `|`, and then som link text. I only want to count the link text towards the max limit of the textarea, so while they have an open `[##`, I want to disable the char count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I should use   negative lookahead assertion with a negated char class present inside that.

```
string.match(/\[##(?![^\[\]]*#\])/g)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eT2rO2/2)

Comment: I couldn't accept that quickly due to stackoverflow no letting you :) One problem though; if the user types `[` somewhere, it won't work. Is it possible to trigger on `[##` specifically, not just `[`?

Comment: try `\[##(?![^\[\]]*#\])`, if not then post an example.